# How do I stop pop ups on the desktop on Windows 10?

Tags: windows

How do I stop pop ups on the desktop on Windows 10?
These are not pop up ads that happen on a web site.
They happen on my desktop as little pop ups in the lower right corner of my computer screen.
They look like this video I recorded here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YLKT8F4kx6g

I do not know if they are tied somehow to another program working -- like the Windows 10 mail program -- or if they are a feature of chrome, but they are outside any other running program.

These are NOT pop up ads on Youtube.  These are on my desktop.  And they must have something to do with Chrome because most say so:
[image: https://aws1.discourse-cdn.com/sitepoint/original/3X/c/4/c417189c8471a02f211d94ebf524e605ccc21c34.png]

Now, I know that the obvious route to figuring this out is to run a search engine and ask how to stop the chrome pop up ads.  But eventhough doing this gave me the steps required to do that, I found it did nothing.  So, I imagine that there are completely different kinds of pop up ads that go inside the chrome browser and this is somehow something different that I am experiencing.

I figured it might have something to do with a program that is run when the system starts.  Here is what CCleaner has to say about what is run at start up:
[image: https://aws1.discourse-cdn.com/sitepoint/original/3X/c/8/c893dd90b2288917d66a31a880d66ddfb1eba95b.png]
[image: https://aws1.discourse-cdn.com/sitepoint/original/3X/9/b/9b25dd90e7436cf73b32bd3680ecc1ca5d5b0a18.png]
[image: https://aws1.discourse-cdn.com/sitepoint/original/3X/f/e/fe4066243778aea4108835fd3c6d0b50f913b4ed.png]
[image: https://aws1.discourse-cdn.com/sitepoint/original/3X/0/e/0ec5330c26657aeae4f1a535acb9acb4cda2bad5.png]

Comment: This is a forum for *hardware* questions.  Try https://superuser.com/